# Invalid conversion from int to int* error for a function with void return type

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

So, I need to get the maximum value from an array. So the first input line contains the number of array elements, then the values for the array. But I am really confused as to why this error keeps popping up when I pass an integer type array to the function. I am finding it a little difficult to deal with pointers and functions at the moment.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void maxim(long long int nums[],long long int n){
    int max_val=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(nums[i]>max_val){
            max_val=nums[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<max_val<<endl;
}
int main() {
    long long int n;
    cin>>n;
    long long int arr[n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    maxim(arr[n],n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should pass `arr` instead of `arr[n]` as `maxim(arr,n);`.

Comment: `long long int arr[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value.  Instead, use `std::vector<long long> arr(n);`.  Also, `n` is not initialized, and you are using it, which is wrong.

Comment: *So, I need to get the maximum value from an array* -- Is this what you want to do?  If so, then your attempt is far from how to actually achieve this goal in C++.  Why not simply use `std::min_element`?

Comment: It's still wrong. [Variable Length Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (like your `long long int arr[n]`) are not valid C++ (according to the standard). You should use [std::vector<long long int>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead which is the proper and idiomatic replacement for this.

Comment: Should say `std::max_element`, not `std::min_element`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void maxim(long long int *nums,long long int n){
    long long int max_val=nums[0];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(nums[i]>max_val){
            max_val=nums[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<max_val<<endl;
}
int main() {
    long long int n;
    long long int *arr;
    cin>>n;
    arr = new long long int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    maxim(arr,n);
    delete []arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it should be `maxim(arr,n);`, not `maxim(arr[n],n);`

Comment: Could you elaborate what was wrong in the question?

Comment: long long int arr[n]; // this is static array. but c++ doesn't support this and n must be constant. It must be used dynamic memory allocating with new and delete operators.

Comment: This answer still has flaws.  `int max_val=0;` -- The type that is passed is a pointer to `long long`, not `int`.  If one of the values in the array exceeds the range of an `int`, the function will fail.  The second thing is that this will fail if all the values in the array are negative.

Comment: you are right.  I edited "int max_val = nums[0];"

Comment: @Nikita `max_val` shouldn't be an `int`.  See my updated comment.

Comment: @Nikita start the forloop with `i=1`

Comment: @Nikita All of the comments as to how you should change your answer is the exact reason why `std::cout << *std::max_element(arr, arr + n);` should be used.  With that simple call, everything works without any of the potential issues.  It took you 4 or 5 edits to get the code (at least on the surface) to work.

Comment: std::cout << *std::max_element(arr, arr + n-1); Is it right?

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1?  [See the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).  The second argument is a pointer to one item *after* the last item to be used.  That's why documentation for functions such as `std::max_element` uses the *range* syntax: `[first, last)` -- note the `)` instead of `]` as the close of the range.

Comment: arr is pointer of arr[0], and arr+n-1 is pointer of arr[n-1]. 0~n-1 contains n elements. right?

Comment: What does this have to do with how to properly utilize `std::max_element`?  If you want proof that whatever you were proposing does *not* work:  `int arr[3] = {1,2,3}; std::cout << *std::max_element(arr, arr + 2);` -- what value will print out?  It will not be `3`, since `3` would not have been included in the test for maximum value.  The right way would be: `*std::max_element(arr, arr + 3);`